# Python tree traversal recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, tree

I have a segment tree which holds data for a range of numbers (data structure chosen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644737/data-structure-for-large-ranges-of-consecutive-integers)). Here's the code:

```
class SegmentTree:
    def __init__(self, N):
        def _init(b, e):
            if b is e:
                data = foo() # No dependency
                return Node(b, e, data, None, None)
            else:
                mid = (b + e ) / 2

                L = _init(b, mid)
                R = _init(mid + 1, e)

                data = foo() #Data depends on L and R

                return Node(b, e, data, L, R)

        self.root = _init(1, N)
```

This fails for N around 300 with a max recursion depth exceeded error. Is there a way to create the tree iteratively instead of recursively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real problem is not the recursion depth of your algorithm, which should be about 10 for a value like 300, but that you are comparing numbers with `is`. The `is` keyword checks for object identity, while `==` checks for equality:

```
>>> 300 == 299+1
True
>>> 300 is 299+1
False
```

Because of that your `if` condition that should terminate the recursion will never be true and the function will keep recursing, even if `b` and `e` are equal.

If you change the `if` this problem should go away:

```
if b == e:
   ...
```

For small numbers the problem might not occur because Python ["caches" and reuses the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058948/python-identity-problem-multiple-personality-disorder-need-code-shrink) for ints up to a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the way you convert from recursion to iterative, is to maintain the stack (or queue) manually.

Something like:

```
 while stack is not empty:
     item = pop from stack

     do processing (such as adding onto the node)

     push L and R onto the stack
```

The stack does grow in memory, since for each item you are popping, you are pushing two.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do this, but I need to do my processing on the current node after (recursively) creating the L and R nodes. I'm not sure where/how to stash the current node for future processing - on a separate stack?

Comment: Well there are usually better ways to implement tree traversal (though they can get complicated with pointer twiddling and stuff) instead of using a "stack". After all if you use a stack on the heap you aren't really saving much space (well apart from a constant factor because you need to save less state)