# algorithm - How to concatenate two binary search tree efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am **not** asking how to merge two binary search trees, as this question did [How to merge two BST's efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008513/how-to-merge-two-bsts-efficiently)

I am really asking how to *concatenate* two trees. So if tree A's all nodes are smaller than any node of tree B, we can concatenate two trees. But how do I do it efficiently?

My idea is to find tree B's minimum, and then let tree A be the left child of minimum(tree B).

This is simple enough and the time is `O(height of B)`.

But I guess this solution has some problems:

1. it may cause the final big tree not balanced any more
2. What if the worst case running time is `O(h)`, where `h` is the max height of the two tree?

Actually, The book "[Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/)" has this excise. Is my simple solution enough for this exercise?

> A concatenate operation takes two sets S1 and S2, where every key in S1 is smaller than any key in S2, and merges them together. **Give an algorithm to concatenate two binary search trees into one binary search tree**. The worst-case running time should be O(h), where h is the maximal height of the two trees.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let A be the smaller set. Assume x = maximum_element(A) and y = minimum_element(B).

We know x < y. take a node with key value equal to `z = (x+y)/2` and make A its left subtree and B its right subtree. remove the added node(with key `z`) from this BST.

Comment: just to be clear, this is better than your answer, Jackson, because it's less likely to unbalance things.

Comment: @andrewcooke, yes, you are right. Just make the answer more clear here: after find x and y, delete y from B, and let y be the new root, y.right = B.root, y.left = A.root. I guess this description is more clear than involving a temp z node. thanks

Comment: There are two problems with this answer: 1. You don't know which tree is smaller, and can't determine that in O(h) time. 2. The solution asks for a O(h) solution, without regard for balancedness.

Comment: @Tom, we can actually determine this in `O(h)` time, because `h` is the maximal height of the two trees. Therefore I think that Jackson's answer is also acceptable, but this one produces better (in terms of balance) result-tree. I also like your answer for minimum height

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to define:

- `h_A` = max height of `A`
- `h_B` = max height of `B`
- `h = min(h_A, h_B)`

Your solution's worst case running time is `O(h_B)`, which happens when the depth of `min(B)` is `h_B`.

The question asked for a `O(h_B)` worst case. A `O(h)` solution is preferable, since if `h_B` is much larger than `h_A`, we'd be better off attaching `B` to the right child of `max(A)` than your current solution, which attaches `A` to the left child of `min(B)`.

Here's how to do that:

1. Recursively traverse down the right of `A`, and the left of `B`.
2. Stop traversing when you get to *either* `max(A)` or `min(B)`.
3. One of three things is possible:
4. You got to `max(A)`. In this case, set `max(A).right = B`
5. You got to `min(B)`. In this case, set `min(B).left = A`
6. You got to `max(A)` *and* `min(B)`. In this case, do either of the above options.

At most we traversed `h_A` or `h_B` steps, whichever is smaller. That is, `h` steps. Attaching one tree to an element is constant. Thus the running time is O(h).

Comment: Why do you have `h = min(h_A, h_B)` if in the question `h` is defined as the **maximal** height of the two trees?

Comment: "The question asked for a O(h_B) worst case. A O(h) solution is preferable, since if h_B is much larger than h_A, we'd be better off attaching B to the right child of max(A) than your current solution, which attaches A to the left child of min(B)."