# merging two binary search trees

Tags: c++, data-structures, merge, binary-search-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i can merge two binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152470/how-i-can-merge-two-binary-trees)

I'm new to trees codes and I've been asked to write a code for merging two binary search trees by writing a function

```
void mergeBst (BST & othertree)
```

This function will receive another Bst and insert all non- redundant values from that tree to the current tree so can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: You take all the elements from one tree and add them to the other.

Comment: How much code do you already have?

Comment: Think about how you would merge two sorted ranges abstractly first. Then apply this thinking to trees.

Comment: Here's a clue. Google for the words in the title of your question here and read what it finds.

Comment: I have lots of other functions to write and I'm working on them but in the merging code I have none

Answer (score 3):

Create two sorted list using two trees. This will be O(m+n).Then merge two sorted list maintaining order.(O(m+n)) Create composed tree using the merged list.(O(m+n))

Or simply
for every node in the input tree, find the position to insert node into the source tree. Then insert it.

[How i can merge two binary trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152470/how-i-can-merge-two-binary-trees)

[How to merge two BST's efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008513/how-to-merge-two-bsts-efficiently)

Answer (score 1):

To merge tree B into tree A (`A.mergeBst(B)`):

Compare the root of B to the root of A.
If the root of B is greater, merge `B.left` into A, and the rest of B into `A.right`.
If it's less, merge `B.right` into A, and the rest of B into `A.left`.
If they're equal, merge `B.left` into `A.left`, `B.right` into `A.right`, and discard the root of B.

Comment: I don't think this will always yield the correct merge. Consider trees (1,2,3) with 2 as root and (1,3,5) with 3 as root. Your algorithm will have 1 appear twice.

Comment: @user315052: drat, you're right. Hang on...

Comment: I think your new algorithm is now much closer. But, you have to also consider that the result of a merge may cause the root value to change. So, for example, the step "merge the rest of B into A.right" may not be correct after the first step of "merge B.left into A". For that particular case, I would change the order of the merges.

Comment: @user315052: can you give an example that *requires* the root value to change?

Comment: The BST may be self-balancing (e.g. Red-Black or AVL).

Comment: @user315052: the OP made no requirement that the resultant tree be self-balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Considering two Binary Search Trees:

1. **Source** - the BST on which you will iterate
2. **Target** - the BST you wish to add source's values

There is a pretty simple algorithm.

for each "values" in **source** search if they are in **target** if they are, discard them, if not insert them.

EDIT:
by "iterate" i meant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Pre-order iteration:

1. Visit the root.
2. Traverse the left subtree.
3. Traverse the right subtree.

Comment: Your answer is about as vague as the original question.  What does it mean to iterate over a binary search tree, to "for each 'values'" in it?